# Namespacing JSONAPI resource and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

I'm trying to add a namespace to my 'Category' controller and resource.

So the first thing I did was to move the `categories_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller` and the `category_resource.rb` to `app/resources/api/v1/`

And then I redeclared these artifacts as following:

**Controller**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
      #before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
    end
  end
end
```

**Resource**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CategoryResource < JSONAPI::Resource
      attribute :name
    end
  end
end
```

And in `routes.rb` I moved the categories route to

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    jsonapi_resources :categories
  end
end
```

I already got different erros trying to solve this issue. To the current configuration, this is the error I get:

> JSONAPI: Could not find resource 'categories'. (Class CategoryResource not found) (NameError)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation here (https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) you should not move the resource.

And it should not be in the modules.

Comment: hey, thanks for writing back. I'm following this part of the guide https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources#namespaces

Comment: when I start rails

Comment: No stacktrace? In what file is it thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine - I have something similar with jsonapi-resources 0.7.0:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController
...
class Api::V1::UserResource < BaseResource
...
namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do
  jsonapi_resources :users do
    jsonapi_relationships
  end
```

is it possible your rails load path is trying to load the `api/v1` directory directly rather than treating it as a module subfolder?